# Booking a return flight, but from a different place

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings

I am a bit of newbie in airline tickets booking matrix.
Here is my situation:
I have to travel from            A -> B.
But I will return like this: C -> A.

B -> C travel will be land based private transport.

One way trips are expensive and I do not find this option of specifying "C" in the ticket booking websites.

Any pointers?

Comment: It's called an open-jaw flight, btw

Comment: Another term used by airlines is "ARNK".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called an open-jaw flight/ticket, and you usually have to deal with it and buy two one-way tickets. Most bookings sites will allow multi-city options.

For example, on [Matrix Airfare Search](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/), you can choose the multi-city option. Then you can specify which date ranges you want to take the A-B and C-A option.

Sometimes it's cheaper, sometimes it's more expensive, sometimes people use hidden-ticket options or drop the return leg, but there are risks involved in these tricks (See other questions on this site for those topics).

Comment: Just putting this link where it gives an almost step by step instruction how to go about Open Jaw tickets.
http://maphappy.org/2014/05/how-to-book-cheap-open-jaw-tickets/

Comment: If you are buying an open jaw on an single airline, it is a round trip fare, not two one way tickets. The fare is calculated by taking half of each city pair's round trip airfare for the class of seats available.